# How to find my own organization id?

Tags: ibm-cloud

In many of the APIs for Bluemix, I need to know my "organization id" which I believe to be different from the "name" of my organization.  When I login to the Bluemix dashboard, I am unable to find my organization id value.  What is the recommended set of steps to determine my own organization id value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cf command line tool for this:

```
$ cf org <org-name> --guid
```

You can also see it in the Bluemix dashboard browser URL, like for example (I modified mine below for security reasons):

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/#/resources/cloudOEPaneId=resources&**orgGuid=xxxxxxxx-8afc-4b2f-afb5-dc7d77dd0baa**&spaceGuid=xxxxxxx-2c29-4d8a-9e97-06aed

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll try that.  I assume that there is no browser/dashboard based quick lookup mechanism?

Comment: I updated the answer with option to see from browser URL